# Unexplained height re sizing in a JQuery autocomplete input field in a ui dialog

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to solve a bug and I have no idea what is causing it.

The input field of a JQuery autocomplete's height is set to 149px:

[image]

I don't know what is modifying `element.style`.

The URL of my testing site is: http://testing.tostaky.biz/k/kamachumu.html, click on one of the magnifiers to open the JQuery box.

What is the cause of this height re-size?

**More information:**

The CSS for this input item:

```
#lts {
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #010109;
    padding-left: 2px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it is a regression:

```
<div id="cts" title="Type In Your City/Timezone">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input id="lts" title="Input City/Timezone" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had removed `id="cts"` on the top div and initialized the dialog on `id="lts"`. Restoring the initial code solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dialog is being created with the  element directly. Something like `<input id="input">` and `$("#input").dialog();`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gVGU/. The input then grows to fill the height of its dialog container.

What you ought to do is put your input inside a `<div>` and create your dialog with that. Something like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <input>
</div>
```

and then `$("#dialog").dialog();`

Comment: This solves half the issue, but when I test it, the autocomplete does not work anymore...